# How to add ' before and after number

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I am new to Excel I have a around 3000 purchase numbers and I need add `'` before and after the numbers, and I need a `,` after each row's closing `'`.

Eg:

```
'18-0000319-000',
'44-000000123-000',
'55-00000456-010',
```

Don't know how to do in Excel please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have data in C3, here is the formula that will do the trick:

```
="'"&C3&"',"
```

and you may then drag it down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of two/three (depending on version) ways to achieve this. Assuming your purchase numbers are in `A2` down:

`="'"&A2&"',"`

`=CONCAT("'",A2,"',")` Newer versions of Excel uses this as well

`=CONCATENATE("'",A2,"',")` This is the older version of excel's Concatenate formula

Comment: How to check duplicate value in Excel for eg in one column

Comment: Highlight the data range, go to conditional formatting, select `Highlight Cell Rules` and select `Duplicate Values`